# Set a variable undefined and null

Tags: jquery, variables

I just read some code and i see this line:

```
var foo = null, undefined;
```

When i test the variable it is both null and undefined.

Thus my question, **What is the purpose to set a variable both null and undefined ?**
I don't get it.
Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: `foo` variable will be `null`, `undefined` is useless in the above statement

Comment: thus,this declaration makes a dead code?

Comment: Be careful when checking undefined, use === or typeof

Comment: how you check that variable _it is both null and undefined_?

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, you are likely not testing foo in the correct manner, a variable cannot be both undefined **and** null.

```
var foo = null, undefined;
alert(foo); //shows null
alert(typeof foo); //shows object (not undefined)
```

So what's going on?  The comma indicates that you are declaring an additional variable.  Since undefined is a keyword already, this particular part of the statement has no effect.  However, if you did it like this:

```
var foo = null, undefined1;
alert(foo); //shows null
alert(typeof foo); //shows object (not undefined)
alert(undefined1); //shows undefined
alert(typeof undefined1); //shows undefined
```

You can see that you are actually declaring a new variable, `undefined1`, that has no initial value.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of that statement is to have a local declaration of [`undefined`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined) in a variable with the same name.

For example:

```
// declare two local variables
var foo = null, undefined;

console.log(foo === undefined); // false
```

It's similar to:

```
function test(foo, undefined)
{
    console.log(foo === undefined); // false
}
test(null); // only called with a single argument
```

This isn't typically necessary because a sane browser will not allow anyone to redefine what `undefined` means and [jslint](http://www.jslint.com) will complain about this:

> Reserved name 'undefined'.

Basically, I would recommend not doing this at all:

```
var foo = null;
```

Btw, the above declaration is not to be confused with using the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) in this manner:

```
var foo;

foo = 1, 2;
console.log(foo); // 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Short:  That's useless

without assigning anything a variable is `undefined`. You can assign `null` to make it null. However your comparison also matters

[Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/c6aozkf5/)

```
if(foo == null) //true
    alert('1');
if(foo == undefined) //true
    alert('2');
```

Now strict comparison having `===`

```
if(foo === null) //false............can be true if assigned to null
    alert('3');
if(foo === undefined) //true.......can be flase if assigned to null
    alert('4');
```